# Out Of Memory Mysql (MariaDB) Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, out-of-memory, mariadb

I suddenly bump into an error in MariaDB (mysql)

Error Code: 5. Out of memory (Needed 3758098168 bytes)

This is my configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
max_connection=60
datadir=/data/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G
skip-external-locking
query_cache_size= 256M
key_buffer_size=20M
table_open_cache=400
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_buffer_size=20M
join_buffer_size=30M
```

The query contains loads of Left outer Join... So I assumed it must be the join_buffer_size that had to be increased.. I changed it from 3M to 30M, but it still crashes.

This is the query:

```
SELECT Periods.Periods, Result.count as `Result`, Studies.count as  `Studies`, 
MouthStudies.Mouthcount as `MOU`,
LiverStudies.LiverCount as `LIV`,
BreastStudies.BreastCount as `BRE`,
BladderStudies.BladderCount as `BLA`,
CervixStudies.CervixCount as `CER`,
ProstateStudies.ProstateCount as `PRO`, 
ColorectalStudies.ColorectalCount + ColonStudies.ColonCount as COL,
LungStudies.LungCount as LUN,
KidneyStudies.KidneyCount as KID,
EndometrianStudies.EndometrianCount as `END`,
GallbladderStudies.GallbladderCount as `GAL`,
NasopharynxStudies.NasopharynxCount as `NAS`,
ObesityStudies.ObesityCount as `OBE`,
OesophagealStudies.OesophagealCount as `OES`,
OvarianStudies.OvarianCount as OVA,
PancreasStudies.PancreasCount as PAN,
SkinStudies.SkinCount as SKI,
StomachStudies. StomachCount as STM,
PolypesStudies.PolypesCount as POL

from
(select DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(allDates.`DATETIME`,'%M - %Y')) as Periods
from 
(select `DATETIME` 
from tblresults
union all
select `DATETIME` 
from tblstudydetailsmain) as allDates
order by `DATETIME` DESC LIMIT 3)  as Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, count(ID) as `count` FROM central_log.tblresults 
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as Result
ON Periods.periods=Result.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, count(ID) as `count` FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where USER LIKE concat('','%')  and USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added'
GROUP BY periods
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as Studies
ON Periods.periods=Studies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'mou%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Mouthcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where USER LIKE concat('','%')  and USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as MouthStudies
ON Periods.periods=MouthStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'LIV%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Livercount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where USER LIKE concat('','%')  and USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as LiverStudies
ON Periods.periods=LiverStudies.Periods


LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'BRE%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Breastcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as BreastStudies
ON Periods.periods=BreastStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'BLA%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Bladdercount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as BladderStudies
ON Periods.periods=BladderStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'CER%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Cervixcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as CervixStudies
ON Periods.periods=CervixStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'PRO%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Prostatecount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as ProstateStudies
ON Periods.periods=ProstateStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'COL%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Coloncount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as ColonStudies
ON Periods.periods=ColonStudies.Periods


LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'LUN%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Lungcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as LungStudies
ON Periods.periods=LungStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'KID%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Kidneycount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as KidneyStudies
ON Periods.periods=KidneyStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'END%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Endometriancount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as EndometrianStudies
ON Periods.periods=EndometrianStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'CRC%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Colorectalcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as ColorectalStudies
ON Periods.periods=ColorectalStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'GAL%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Gallbladdercount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as GallbladderStudies
ON Periods.periods=GallbladderStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'NAS%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Nasopharynxcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as NasopharynxStudies
ON Periods.periods=NasopharynxStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'OBE%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Obesitycount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as ObesityStudies
ON Periods.periods=ObesityStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'oes%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Oesophagealcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as OesophagealStudies
ON Periods.periods=OesophagealStudies.Periods

LEFT  OUTER  JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'OVA%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Ovariancount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as OvarianStudies
ON Periods.periods=OvarianStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'PAN%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Pancreascount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as PancreasStudies
ON Periods.periods=PancreasStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'SKI%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Skincount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as SkinStudies
ON Periods.periods=SkinStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'STM%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Stomachcount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as StomachStudies
ON Periods.periods= StomachStudies.Periods

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') as periods, 
sum(CASE WHEN WCRF_CODE LIKE 'POL%' then 1 else 0 END) as `Polypescount` 
FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
and TYPE_ACTION LIKE 'added' 
GROUP BY periods 
order by `DATETIME` DESC) as PolypesStudies
ON Periods.periods= PolypesStudies.Periods;
```

Basically, it is a log database of all the added/deleted/updated studies in the main database by type of cancer. It is used here to keep an eye on the production of the team. In total there are only 12,457 rows in the table and until yesterday the query returned no error....

If some MySql-MariaDB performance guru are around, please help me to resolve this!

Christophe

Comment: 3758098168 bytes are about 3.7 **Giga**byte!

Comment: Check the explain of the query first to see if any of the subqueries have too many rows.

Comment: I tried the explain, but I get the same error message...

Comment: I am thinking of perhaps rewrite the query without too much join...

Comment: Yes, Just tried to rewrite my query and this time no problem... Sorry to waste your time @Shadow

Comment: How many rows in `select DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(allDates.DATETIME,'%M - %Y'))` ?

Comment: `order by DATETIME DESC` does nothing useful.

Comment: `select DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(allDates.DATETIME,'%M - %Y'))` returned 29 rows when not limited to 3. here I limit only to the 3 last month for which I  have data.... It is true though that `order by `DATETIME` DESC`  in all the other queries do nothing uselful . Thanks  @RickJames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider replacing all the JOINs by...

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Periods`DATETIME`, '%M - %Y') AS Periods,  -- see note below
    Result.count as `Result`,
    Studies.count as  `Studies`, 
    ( SELECT sum(WCRF_CODE LIKE 'BLA%')
         FROM central_log.tblstudydetailsmain
         where  USER NOT LIKE 'rroot%'
           and TYPE_ACTION = 'added' 
           AND `DATETIME` >= Periods.periods
           AND `DATETIME`  < Periods.periods + INTERVAL 1 MONTH  -- note
    ) AS 'BLA',   -- a "correlated subquery"
    ( SELECT ...
    ) AS 'MOU',
    ...
FROM ( SELECT DATE(`DATETIME`)   -- See note below
        ... ) AS Periods
```

Note...  I want to use month-start values, such as '2015-06-01' instead of your `DATETIME` or `Jun - 2015`.  Instead, construct that at the last moment.  The month-start is also needed for `DATETIME  < Periods.periods + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.  So, if `DATETIME` is not always the start of a month, some further edits are needed.

Comment: Seems that I made a really bad query at first. Whith you data it was okay. :s  I learned that the more joins the more memory consuming the query will be! Many thanks for your solution @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

I think my query was scrap and rewriting it resolve this instead of using many join I made  a flat dataset with (union all) and using CASE WHEN to count the studies in each categories...